# Obtener informacion de un checkbox en una table

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una tabla donde la relleno con checkbox, antes pregunto si el usuario esta en un tabla de permisos en caso que se encuentre me marca el checkbox y si no me lo deja para marca.
Aqui mi tabla

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>
        <th>Opcion</th>

    </tr>
    <?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
    <?php while ($r=$query->fetch_array()):?>
    <?php $total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Codigo from Maestro_PerfilUsuarios where Codigo = $persona->Codigo  AND Acceso_CodMenu ='$r[Cod_Menu]'")); ?>
    <tr>
        <?php if ($total==0): ?>
        <td>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="permiso[]" value="<?php echo $r[" Cod_Menu "] ?>" class="custom-control-input" id="<?php echo $id.$i; ?>">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="<?php echo $id.$i; ?>">
                    <?php echo $r["Opcion"] ?></label>
            </div>
        </td>

        <?php else: ?>
        <td>
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="permiso[]" value="<?php echo $r[" Cod_Menu "] ?>" class="custom-control-input" id="<?php echo $id.$i; ?>" checked>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="<?php echo $id.$i; ?>">
                    <?php echo $r["Opcion"] ?></label>
                <button type="button" title="Quitar Permiso" name="btn_delete" onclick="QuitarPermiso()" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i+=1; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif;?>
</table>
```

Aqui mi javacritps donde obtengo el text de un td

```
function QuitarPermiso() {
            $('#dataTable tr').on('click', function() {
                //    var first = $(this).find('td:first').html();
                var first = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
                alert(first);

            });

        }
```

Lo que deseo es poder obtener el `value="<?php echo $r[" Cod_Menu "] ?>"` de un input en ese td, como lo haria ?

Comment: ¿Puedes ser un poco más específico? Según entiendo, quieres obtener el valor de un checkbox que esta dentro de un td al hacer click sobre el. ¿Eso es lo que buscas?

Comment: No acabo de entender la pregunta. Cuando quieres obtener el value del input? en la funcion de `QuitarPermiso()` ?

Comment: @Cenlan Asi es, y despues pasar ese variable a un json para hacer un delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende del tipo de input del que quieras tomar un valor. Viendo que utilizas un checkbox, quedaría de esta forma.

```js
function QuitarPermiso() {
    $('#dataTable td').on('click', function() {
        var first = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked")
        alert(first);
    });
}
```

Esto devolveria true o false dependiendo de si el checkbox esta chequeado o no. Sin embargo, si lo que quieres es guardar una cadena de texto dentro del value de un checkbox, puedes utilizar .val() en vez de .is(":checked")